# Call magento image section in my custom phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, magento-1.9.3.6

I am using Magento 1.9.3.6 version.

I want to get and show the Product Image section as like Product Detail Page in my custom phtml.

How to get it.

[image]

**Update:**
my layout.xml file content:

```
<block type="custom/myblock" name="custom_myblock" after="-" template="custom/mytemplate.phtml">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.media.after" as="after" />
     </block>
</block>
```

And Calling in mytemplate.phtml as follows:

```
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-img-box">
            <div class="product-name">
                <h1><?php echo $_helperOutput->productAttribute($product, $product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
   </div>
```

and Getting this error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getTypeInstance() on null in ../app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Abstract.php on line 44`

Answer (score 2):

Use below code in your layout.xml

```
<page_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</page_index_index>
```

Then in your controller action file use below code

```
public function indexAction() {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(408); // set product id here
    Mage::register('current_product', $product);
    Mage::register('product', $product);
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_title(Mage::helper('confirmnl')->__('Product image'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

It will display product image block on your page url.

TO soleve getTypeInstance error you need to add current_product in controller

Answer (score 0):

As per the `RWD` theme in Magento, this section renders by `catalog_product_gallery` layout which you can find it from

`app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\catalog.xml`

and the main `PHTML` file is responsible for this section is 
 `catalog/product/gallery.phtml` and the main Block is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Gallery` so just take a look at this sections and try.

If you are using some custom theme then please check your theme `layout` file and `PHTML` file.

Comment: I am using custom theme and Created layout and Phtml. But the images not rendering.

Comment: What is your block type of PHTML file ?

Comment: Updated Question. Pls check it.